# Why does the photo app take 28GB even though I remove all the files from Windows and my iCloud capability is capped to 5GB?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I use an iPhone 12 mini with iOS 15. I connected the phone to my Windows laptop and I removed all the files I could see on Windows explorer. However, the photo app takes 28GB, how is it possible?

---

The photo app takes 28GB:

[image]

[image]

I don't see any shared albums in the photo app:

[image]

My iCloud capability is capped to 5GB:

[image]

After connecting the iPhone to Windows, I saw many folders in the `DCIM` folder, and I removed all the files:

[image]

Comment: Has someone shared albums with you?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz thanks, I don't see any shared albums in the photo app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNb05.png

Comment: Were the photos moved to "Recently Deleted?" Also, it says you have 700 photos - are those supposed to be deleted?

Comment: I can't remember the behavior in Windows, but you have to empty the trash after deleting on macOS, maybe you have a hidden Trash folder?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz thanks, I don't see any thrash folder on Windows for the iPhone. I emptied the thrash folder in `C:\$Recycle.Bin` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the photo app take 28GB even though I remove all the files from Windows and my iCloud capability is capped to 5GB?

The issue is caused by the presence of photos and videos on my phone that don't show up when I connect the iPhone to Windows. I don't know why that's the case though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Windows PC need to use iTunes to access Photos on an iPhone/iPad. Here is what Apple Support says about it (2023):

**Import to your Windows PC**

You can import photos to your PC by connecting your device to your computer and using the Windows Photos app:

1. Update to the latest version of iTunes on your PC. Importing photos
   to your PC requires iTunes 12.5.1 or later.
2. Connect your iPhone or iPad to your PC with a USB cable.
3. If asked, unlock your iOS or iPadOS device using your passcode.
4. If you see a prompt on your iOS or iPadOS device asking you to Trust This Computer, tap Trust or Allow to continue.
5. Then, visit Microsoft's website to learn how to
   import photos to the Windows Photos app in Windows 10 or Windows 11.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201302